# Powershell Script that creates a network share on a remote computer

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I am currently writing a powershell script that creates a network share on a remote computer in Windows 7. I am able to create the folder, but am unable to create the correct path for the folder.

I'm fairly new to powershell, so my terminology may be a little off. Bear with me.

This is what I have so far:

```
([wmiclass]'\\REMOTECOMPUTER\root\cimv2:Win32_Share').Create("D:\User_Data", $alias, 0, 1, $alias + " U:\ Drive")
```

The above works, but I want to make the folder path read `D:\User_Data\$alias`. `$alias` is just the variable for the user's folder.

I've tried:

```
.Create("D:\User_Data\" + $alias

.Create("D:\User_Data" + "\" + $alias

.Create("D:\User_Data\$alias" ....

$FolderPath = "D:\User_Data\" + $alias

.Create($FolderPath .....
```

I've tried those, but when I do the share isn't created at all. Everything else in the script works however.

Comment: I forgot to add that to things I have tried. It's since been updated. When I try that, I get no error message but then no network share is created.

Comment: No, the path does not exist

Comment: I see. Any idea why it would work when I leave it like: Create("D:\User_Data" ? Because that folder does not exist either. It's only when I try to add to the path where I encounter issues.

Comment: I get a return value of 24, although I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Unknown device or directory (24)

Comment: I got that when I tried to hardcode $alias into a string (perhaps I did that incorrectly). I get a return value of 0 when I do it the original way. .Create("D:\User_Data"

Comment: if you only have D:\User_Data in the call, does the directory get created on the remote pc?

Comment: Yes. If only D:\User_Data is created on the remote pc, then I get 0. Anytime I try to modify it, everything else script wise works except the network share creation and I get the return value of 24.

Comment: what i mean is, if you go on the remote pc and check D:\, is the directory User_Data existant? if so delete it and run the wmi call again. just to make sure

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is string expansion.  If you use double quotes and have a variable name within, that will be expanded.  `$u='cup'; "$u"` In this example, `$u` will be expanded to `cup`

```
$rpc = REMOTEPCNAME
$Share = [wmiclass]"\\$rpc\root\cimv2:Win32_Share"

If (!(GWMI Win32_Share -ComputerName $rpc -Filter 'Path="U:\"'))
{
    $Share.Create("D:\User_Data\$Alias", $Alias, 0, 1, "$Alias U:\ Drive")
}
```